# Error while running Selenium docs example using Firefox

Tags: python, firefox, selenium

I am extremely new to programming and have recently learnt a bit of python to get around. As part of my project I need to open, feed a webform and download an image and as I have to do this umpteen times, I looked around if there is any way to automate it using Python. That's when I came across Selenium. I was just running the example in its documentation and faced problems while using firefox.

While running Selenium example code as given here [Selenium docs example code](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/getting-started.html)

I get a large error which is as follows:

```
 driver = webdriver.Firefox()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 51, in __init__
    self.binary, timeout),
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/extension_connection.py", line 47, in __init__
    self.binary.launch_browser(self.profile)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_binary.py", line 44, in launch_browser
    self._wait_until_connectable()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_binary.py", line 81, in _wait_until_connectable
    self._get_firefox_output())
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'The browser appears to have exited before we could connect.
```

How can I get around this.
I am using python 2.7.6 and the Firefox version is 40.0.3

Comment: What version of Selenium are you using?

Comment: I installed Selenium-2.25.0-0ubuntu1 from the synaptic package manager.

Comment: I don't think that Selenium v2.25 supports firefox v40. Did you try with other versions of firefox browsers and even other browsers too? Probably updating your selenium to latest version might help.

Comment: No, I did not try with other versions of firefox. Yes, I tried it with Chrome and it gave an error of missing webdriver. I went and installed the chrome driver and then the browser window does not open and results in an assertion error like this : " assert "Python" in driver.title AssertionError ".

Comment: Right, if chrome is opening then its the issue in your firefox version. Try using a compatible version of firefox. You got an assertion error because your assert statement in the test script failed.

Comment: Chrome window does not open as I said. Ok, I will use a newer version of Firefox and check. If I make the assert statements as comments, then I get an attribute error: "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send_keys' ".Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium v2.25 doesn't support firefox v40. Either downgrade your browser or upgrade your selenium version.

- Selenium v2.25 supports firefox browser v17.
- Selenium v2.47 supports firefox browser v39.

[Check this page for more details on changelog](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/CHANGELOG). Hope this helps.